# ¿Cómo solucionar el error "Se han detectado errores de #include. Actualice el valor de includePath"?

Tags: c++, vscode

Soy nuevo en el lenguaje c++ y estoy tratado de hacer un nuevo archivo en visual studio code pero me aparece el siguiente error

**"Se han detectado errores de #include. Actualice el valor de includePath."**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que mas hacer para solucionarlo, espero que me ayuden con esto :c

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Crea una carpeta en la raiz de tu proyecto con el nombre .vscode dentro de ella crea un archivo llamado "c_cpp_properties.json"

#c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Windows",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "<Coloca aqui la ruta de las cabeceras del compilador que instalaste>"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "<Coloca aqui el ejecutable del compilador que usas>",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Si usas MinGW la ruta de las cabeceras normalmente la colocas en C:\MinGW\include y el compilador es C:\MinGW\bin\g++